# How to find line intersections with single line equation array in a pythonic way

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, numpy

What would the most pythonic way be, without using for loops, of finding line intersection points in an array comprised of m,c values?

```
lines=np.array([m0,c0],
               [m1,c1],
               [m2,c2],
               ....)
```

achieving the desired result with for loops would consist of something like:

```
for i in lines:
 for n in lines:
   np.linalg.solve(i, n)
```

Comment: `m` is the slope?

Comment: Doesnt seem like the first argument to solve will be a square matrix in this setup; so how is that supposed to work?

Comment: instead of the nested for-loop, you can use [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) to generate the combinations

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, yes the m is the slope, and select any two lines in the matrix and the matrix will become square, and thanks will look into [link]https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The equation for the intersection of two lines `y1 = a1*x + b1` and `y2 = a2*x + b2` is `x = (b2 - b1) / (a1 - a2)`.

By making use of [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) it is easy to compute all intersections between any number of lines:

```
import numpy as np    

# lines of the form y = a * x + b
# with lines = [[a0, b0], ..., [aN, bN]]
lines = np.array([[1, 0], [0.5, 0], [-1, 3], [1, 2]])

slopes = lines[:, 0]  # array with slopes (shape [N])
slopes = slopes[:, np.newaxis]  # column vector (shape [N, 1])

offsets = lines[:, 1]  # array with offsets (shape [N])
offsets = offsets[:, np.newaxis]  # column vector (shape [N, 1])

# x-coordinates of intersections
xi = (offsets - offsets.T) / (slopes.T - slopes) 

# y-coordinates of intersections
yi = xi * slopes + offsets
```

This works by appling the element-wise `-` operator to a column vector of shape [N, 1] and it's transpose of shape [1, N]. The vectors are broadcast to a matrix of shape [N, N].

The final result are two symmetric matrices `xi` and `yi`. Each entry `xi[m, n]` is the intersection of lines `m` and `n`. 
`nan` means the lines are identical (they intersect in every point). `inf` means the lines do not intersect.

Let's show off the result:

```
#visualize the result
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
for l in lines:
    x = np.array([-5, 5])
    plt.plot(x, x * l[0] + l[1], label='{}x + {}'.format(l[0], l[1]))
for x, y in zip(xi, yi)    :
    plt.plot(x, y, 'ko')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Might be important to highlight that when you do `slopes = lines[:, [0]]` (as opposed to `lines[:, 0]`) you're creating a 2D slice instead of the more common 1D slice.  This lets you broadcast using `.T` instead of the more verbose (but also more common) `[None, :]`.  Not everyone can parse fancy indexing in their head like that :)

Comment: @DanielF good point :) Are you sure something like `lines[:, 0][:, np.newaxis]` or `lines[:, np.newaxis, 0]` is more readable?

Comment: It certainly isn't more readable in 2D, but it is more explicit, and therefore more readable when you get beyond 2 dimensions (in my opinion).  For 2D your method is much more readable, but the fancy indexing used to set it up may be confusing for beginners.

Comment: Not to confuse - normally I wouldn't construct the `lines` or `offsets` arrays to be 2D, but would do `xi = (offsets - offsets[none, :]) / (slopes[none, :] - slopes)` - making `xi` 2d explicitly during the broadcast step.  This is less readable than your method, but becomes more readable (imo) as dimensionality gets larger.

Comment: I agree. I would even write `(offsets[:, None] - offsets[None, :])` to make it super explicit.

Comment: Awesome, this is exactly the answer i was looking for, coming from a non-python background, its very difficult to work in matrix form and use all the performance enhancements that that form provides, thanks @kazemakase